# How does the error in azimuth angle vary as one moves away from the boresight direction of a radar

Tags: signal-analysis, signal-detection, measurement, radar

My question is basically same as the title. I am trying to find a mathematical model which provides the error, $d\theta$, in azimuth angle($\theta$) as one moves away from the boresight direction of radar. It is also known that the error in the radar data is also a function of distance ($r$) from the radar. So, in order to incorporate the distance from the radar, can anyone tell me how model $d\theta$ as a function of $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: What kind of radar? Scanning pulse radar, phased array, digital beam forming passive radar....?

Comment: It is a single beam monopulse radar.

Answer (score 1):

This description assumes a planar phased array radar system.

The angle accuracy of a traditional, phase difference, monopulse radar is given by:
$$\sigma = \frac{BW}{k\sqrt{2SNR}}$$
where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the angle estimate, $BW$ is the 3 dB (half-power) beam width, and $SNR$ is the signal-to-noise ratio.  For a typical system the normalized monopulse slope $k=\frac{\pi D}{2\lambda}BW=\frac{\pi}{2}0.886\approx1.39$, where $D$ is the aperture extent and $\lambda$ the wavelength. (see [Derivation of monopulse angle accuracy for phased array radar to achieve Cramer-Rao lower bound](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261091111_Derivation_of_monopulse_angle_accuracy_for_phased_array_radar_to_achieve_Cramer-Rao_lower_bound))

A first order approximation for beamwidth as a function of scan:
$$BW(\theta)\approx\frac{BW_0}{\cos\theta}$$
where $BW_0$ is the broadside beamwidth and $\theta$ is the scan angle away from broadside. (see [Useful approximations for the directivity and beamwidth of large scanning Dolph-Chebyshev arrays](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1448680))

Therefore the angle accuracy as a function of scan is given approximately by:
$$\sigma(\theta) = \frac{BW_0}{k\sqrt{2SNR}\cos\theta}$$

Angle accuracy is not directly a function of range, but does depend on SNR, which holding all other parameters constant, is a function of range.  We can then define a relative angle accuracy change as a function of range.  Keeping all other factors constant, for a radar the SNR is inversely proportional to the fourth power of range, $r$ (see [The Radar Range Equation](https://www.radartutorial.eu/01.basics/The%20Radar%20Range%20Equation.en.html)):
$$SNR(r) = SNR_0\cdot \left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^4$$
where $SNR_0$ is the signal-to-noise ratio at the reference range $r_0$.

Placing this into the expression for angle accuracy:
$$\sigma(r) = \frac{BW}{k\sqrt{2SNR_0\cdot \left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^4}} = \frac{BW}{k\sqrt{2SNR_0}}\cdot\left(\frac{r}{r_0}\right)^2$$